# Spring integration http outbound gateway logging errors

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have an integration flow where I'm reading messages from a jms channel and sending them through a REST api call using http-outbound-gateway.
Now when I get a 5xx Http server error I'd like to log the the URL of the service along with the response message.

I see that the `RestTemplate` instance already logs the URL and calls a `ResponseErrorHandler` which can be a custom implementation.

My problem is: the `ResponseErrorHandler` only receives a `ClientHttpResponse` as a parameter and I can't know the URL from that instance. What I need is to log the server error like: 'Error URL - Response ...'

How can I do that? I can't override `RestTemplate`'s error handling and the `ResponseErrorHandler` doesn't have enough info.

Thank you very much.

Comment: As you write, RestTemplate already logs the URL, so what is the problem?

Comment: I know but there are two problems: first I need it to be ERROR level (it's WARN and I can't set it otherwise) and second it would be nicer to have both URL and Response in the same log line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I see there.

The `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` (`<int-http:outbound-gateway>`) catches all underlying exceptions:

```
catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MessageHandlingException(requestMessage, "HTTP request execution failed for URI ["
                + (realUri == null ? uri : realUri.toString())
                + "]", e);
    }
```

Including the result of that `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` from the `RestTemplate`.
And as you see we use here for the `MessageHandlingException` `uri` as well as the `requestMessage`.

Further this exception will be delegated to that `jms channel`.

Why isn't that enough for you?

From other side you can add `<request-handler-advice-chain>` to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` with `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to get deal with that `MessageHandlingException` just in place: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.
The problem is that the RestTemplate catches the exception and logs it in level warning (RestTemplate line 591) and then the HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler doesn't get to catch the exception.

Comment: Right. But in the end that `RestTemplate#handleResponseError()` invokes `getErrorHandler().handleError(response);`, where the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` throws appropriate `RestClientException`. If you don't override the default one, that exception will be propagated to the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`

Comment: Ok, I got it. I can set an error handler to the jms channel and then the IP is in a nested exception inside the `MessageHandlingException`. Not sure if it's the easiest way, but works for me.
Thank you for your time!